# extjs - dot notation to bracket {} notation?

Tags: extjs

not sure that that is a good title ...

I can get code behind a button to:

```
TabBar.activeTab.setTitle("New Tab");
```

but I need to do something like:

```
TabBar.activeTab.items = { title: "New Tab"
};
```

so I can eventually automate several tab properties in a loop:

```
TabBar.activeTab.items = { [key]: [value]
};
```

Am I correct in thinking config and items can only be used on construct()? Is there a way of doing the above? tia.

Comment: What `items` are in your Tab?!

Comment: TabBar.activeTab.items includes all the grids and charts on this tab. Tab title is at TabBar.activeTab level so I would need  refMainTabBar[0].activeTab ({
title: drtyData[key]
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of the component and config property in question whether it can simply be set or requires a method call to be applied.

You are correct that in ExtJs many config properties are interpreted at construction time. Some are interpreted at render time. Once an `Ext.Component` is rendered almost all properties require an explicit method call to be applied correctly.

In general, I recommend to always use a method call to change a property after construction time if available in order to not break the inner workings of the component. If you look at the implementation of `Ext.panel.Panel#setTitle` you can see that there is a lot of stuff going on under the hood, e.g. event firing, etc.

**ExtJs 4 configuration**

Ext 4 introduced an explicit 'config' mechanism that might serve your purpose. However, my understanding is that most ExtJs components are not (yet?) using it.

Check out '2. Configuration' in the ExtJs [Class System Guide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/class_system)

**Create objects from xtype/config literals**

If you want to add **new** components to a container (e.g. tabs to a tab panel) it would be rather easy to accomplish.

Use `Ext.ComponentManager#create` (see [docs][2]) to create an actual component object/instance from your config literal.

`Ext.container.Container#add` actually calls this method internally, so you can simply pass config objects to the `add` method.

If you want to remove or add tabs to a panel, there is now way around calling the proper methods.

**applyConfig()**

Of course you could always implement your own `applyConfig` method that supports changing certain component configuration properties at runtime by 'translating' the config into the proper method calls.

Comment: with ya. I am converting my Flex Dynamic Dashboard application to extjs. This app has create/modify dashboard frontend which is basically the Architect property manager in runtime mode, rather than in design mode like standard developer tools. Even creating a new dashboard with tabs, widgets etc keeps on updating the runtime gui as you see what you are creating .... with ya. I am converting my Flex Dynamic Dashboard application to extjs. This app has create/modify dashboard frontend which is basically the Architect property manager in runtime mode, rather than in design mode like standard ....

Comment: developer tools. Even creating a new dashboard with tabs, widgets etc keeps on updating the runtime gui as you see what you are creating .... so I am constantly updating the displayed objects as the user works. And because there is very little app and a lot of json metadata, the reason for a lot of [][] is that little engines process json to create the environment and then update the json with the user gui dashboard changes - in Flex of course it was all xml metadata ... I am beginning to really like json! So ...

Comment: I wanna call methods indirectly with TabBar.activeTab[funcNm]([parms]); I think when I tried this is did not work. Presuming it can be done? thanks for all your help ... makes total sense.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help - this works perfectly: var funcNm = "setTitle"; refMainTabBar[0].activeTab[funcNm]([drtyData[key]]);

Comment: Also checkout JavaScript's `apply` and `call` functions. You can do something like this: `activeTab[funcNm].apply(activeTab, paramsArray)`. First parameter sets the 'this' reference for the function cal, second the parameters passed to the function. Not helpful in the case of simple setValue functions, but surely useful in other scenarios.